# how can i fetch data from the database in php?

Tags: php

Here the total rows of company name is 100000 but got the error like 
server unable to handle the request.

```
  <?php
  $servername="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="";
  $dbname="ABC";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
  if($conn){  
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT COMPANY_NAME from mytask "));
$emparray = array();    
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    
   {
    $emparray[] = $row;        
   }  
   var_dump($emparray);
   exit; 
}
else{
 echo "Connection Not Successful"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: cannot execute the code and tell us unable to handle the request.

Comment: you have additional closing bracket on `mysqli_query()` function - remove it.

Comment: Hint: use OOP. Way better

Comment: remove the bracket but got the same error.

Comment: Or PDO with prepared statements!

Comment: is there any problem with my code?

Comment: @RoshanSankhe Did you try fixing the  extra `)`?

Comment: Or prepared statements

Comment: @Webeng read the other comments... "Removed the bracket but got the same error."

Comment: yes @Webeng but got the same error.

Comment: @RoshanSankhe You could try prepared statements, see my answer,

Comment: put `mysqli_error()` on each call to database (connect and query) in order to see any errors...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo, an extra parenthesis. Change the following line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT COMPANY_NAME from mytask "));
```

to this line:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT COMPANY_NAME from mytask ");
```

---

**Edited:**
Also, change the following code:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    
   {
    $emparray[] = $row;        
   }  
   var_dump($emparray);
```

into this code:

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    
   {
      foreach ($row as $value)
      {
         echo "--".$value;
      }
      echo "<br>";     
   }
```

Let me know if it works now.

Comment: @RoshanSankhe can you show us how your table looks? what the name of the table is, and the columns inside.

Comment: @RoshanSankhe just try prepared statements.

Comment: table name is mytask and column contain more than 100000 records

Comment: @RoshanSankhe I see, ok can you copy and paste the exact error. If it says something like `Error:....`? it would be great to see the whole line exactly how it is.

Comment: server says unable to handle the request.

Comment: @RoshanSankhe ok... If you comment out the if -  else conditional, is there an error? If you do: `/*if(...){...}else{...}*/`, that way we can deduce what part of the code is the problem.

Comment: No problem in if else but array unable to handle the large amount of data.

Comment: @RoshanSankhe Ohhh ok, and you want to display the data on the screen correct? I'll update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111826/discussion-between-roshan-sankhe-and-webeng).

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COMPANY_NAME FROM mytask");
$sql = stmt->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch_object()) {
    $emparray[] = $row->COMPANY_NAME;
}
var_dump($emparray);
exit;
```